# Rotate UIButton on table section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UIButton on header of a a section named extendButton. I want to rotate it 180 degree when it's pressed.

```
- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 3) {
        OrderHistoryHeaderView *orderHeaderView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"OrderHistoryHeaderView"];
        if (orderHeaderView == nil) {
            orderHeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderHistoryHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            orderHeaderView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [orderHeaderView.extendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(extendButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        return orderHeaderView;
    }

    ProductDetailHeaderView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"ProductDetailHeaderView"];
    if (headerView == nil) {
        headerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductDetailHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    headerView.mainLabel.text = headerTitleArray[section];
    return headerView;
}


    - (void)extendButtonPressed {
     if (isExtend) {

    //call rotate method
    [self rotateButton:sender];

    //insert row
    unsigned long rowCount = orderHistoryArray.count;

    //show msg if no history data
    if (rowCount == 0) {
        [ShareFunction showSimpleAlertWithString:@"No order history data!!" inVC:self];
    }

    orderHistoryArray = nil;
    NSMutableArray *indexPathSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rowCount; i++) {
        [indexPathSet addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:3]];
    }
    [_mainTableView beginUpdates];
    [_mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [_mainTableView endUpdates];

} else {
    //delete row

    //call rotate method
    [self rotateButton:sender];

    orderHistoryArray = productHistoryArray;

    //show msg if no history data
    //if (orderHistoryArray.count == 0) {
    //    [ShareFunction showSimpleAlertWithString:@"No order history data!!" inVC:self];
    //}


    NSMutableArray *indexPathSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < orderHistoryArray.count; i++) {
        [indexPathSet addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:3]];
    }
    [_mainTableView beginUpdates];
    [_mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [_mainTableView endUpdates];
}

    }
```

And my rotateButton method

```
- (void)rotateButton:(UIButton*)button {
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
}
```

When I tap the button it now can rotate 180 degree and tableView for that section expanded but when I tap again the button stays the same no rotate. What am I missing here?

Comment: You want to animate a 180 degree rotation?

Comment: See if you can figure this out for yourself. Take a look at the `UIView` method `animateWithDuration:animations: `. You want to animate the button's transform property. Also look at the function `CGAffineTransformRotate()`. That function takes a transform and applies a rotation to it. (Hint, M_PI is a 180 degree rotation)

Comment: "but when I tap again the button stays the same no rotate" Because you are asking it to rotate to `M_PI` and it is already there.

Comment: @matt Button image is arrow up. When it's tapped, it rotates and becomes arrow down ...and so on. So it's 180 degree rotate, isn't it?

Comment: Think about what I said.

Comment: The function `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` creates a transform with a given rotation. So your code sets the rotation to π (M_PI, or 180 degrees). The first time you click it, it rotates the button. The second time, it sets the rotation to 180 degrees, but the rotation is already at 180 degrees, so nothing changes. If, instead, you use the function `CGAffineTransformRotate`, you can apply rotation to an existing transform, like `button.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(button.transform, M_PI)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your answer works, but there is a better way.

Use the function CGAffineTransformRotate, which adds rotation to an existing transform:

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(button.transform, M_PI)
```

Next is animating the rotation rather than having the button jump to its new rotation. To do that you can use the `UIView` method `animateWithDuration`.

A button method to rotate the button by 180 degrees would look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
  CGAffineTransform transform = sender.transform;
  transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(sender.transform, M_PI);
  [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations: ^{
    sender.transform = transform;
  }
   ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a solution by passing parameter isExtend

```
- (void)rotateButton:(UIButton*)button isExtend:(BOOL)isExtended{

    if (isExtended) {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    } else {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    }

}
```